# Две проблемы c id и с отправкой текста

Tags: jquery, ajax, php

Здравствуйте.

Первая проблема. У меня есть форма для текста и кнопка.

html

```
<div style="position:relative; left:100px">
    <input type="text" id="poiskt">
    <input type="button" id="poiskb">
</div>
```

и

```
$("#poiskb").click(function () {
    var poiskt = $('#poiskt').val();
    alert(poiskt);
    $.ajax({
        url: "poisk.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            poiskt: poiskt
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});
```

poisk.php

```
$findt = $_POST('poiskt');

$nickbd  = mysql_query("SELECT nick FROM registr WHERE nick='" . $_POST('poiskt') . "'");
$nickbdm = mysql_fetch_assoc($nickbd);
if (mysql_num_rows($nickbd) != 0)
    echo $nickbdm['nick'];

else
    echo 0;
```

alert(poiskt) выдаёт текст, а в poisk.php пишет ошибку "Function name must be a string", хотя в этом документе я также передавал другой текст и без всяких ошибок, в общем не знаю, как исправить, помогите, плз.

А вторая проблема заключается

```
$("input.buttoncom").click(function () {
    var div = this.parentNode;
    var inptext = div.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var textcom = $(не знаю что написать).val();
    alert(textcom);
});
```

В том что `inptext[0].id` является id формы текста, из которой мне текст нужно извлечь и я не знаю, что прописать в скобках, пробовал вот так

```
var textcom=$("#".inptext[0].id."").val();
```

но не сработало, подскажите, плз.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

1

```
$findt=$_POST['poiskt'];

$nickbd=mysql_query("SELECT nick FROM registr WHERE nick='".mysql_real_escape_string($findt)."'");
// надеюсь, ошибка понятна
```

2

inptext[0] - может оказаться еще пустым текстом, но вообще у вас просто неверный подход

```
// var div=this.parentNode;
// var inptext=div.getElementsByTagName('*');
// var textcom=$(не знаю что написать).val();
var textcom = $(this).parent().find('input:text').eq(0).val();
// или например  $(this).closest(':text').val()
alert(textcom);
```

Comment: спасибо, со 2-ой проблемой разобрался, просто недавно учу это всё, разных подходов ещё не знаю.
а вот с первой проблемой пока не как.
у меня ошибка "Function name must be a string" ссылается на $findt=$_POST('poiskt');, но я её решил просто удалить и написать как посоветовали вы $nickbd=mysql_query("SELECT nick FROM registr WHERE nick='".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['poiskt'])."'"); ,
но появляется та же ошибка((

Comment: Проблема в том, что `$_POST` - массив, а не функция :) И обращаться к элементам нужно через `[]`, а не `()`.

    $_POST('index') // неверно
    $_POST['index'] // верно

Так что проверяйте еще раз) Возможно, такая же ошибка есть где-то еще (сообщение об ошибке явно говорит, что она "in __FILE__ on line __LINE__")

Comment: Блин, точно, так и знал, что глупая ошибка где-то, причём везде всегда писал c [], что-то затуманило мне разум. Спасибо!